# Searching a word in different buffers of vim editor

Tags: vim, editor

I have two buffer b1 and b2 opened in vim editor.

If I search a word in b1 and if it is present in b2 what command should I give to highlight that particular word in b2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim searching through all existing buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450887/vim-searching-through-all-existing-buffers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `set hlsearch` in your `~/.vimrc` — the option responsible for highlighting search matches — *all* the matches in *all* your buffers should be highlighted.

[image: hlsearch]